# SIM not detected anymore disabling a SIM

Tags: sim-card, android-13, esim

I have Oneplus 8T with Android 13.

My SIM was on Slot 2 yesterday. Then I accidentally clicked on "Disable SIM".

Now it says "No eSIM" "Disable eSIM to u.." (it only shows second line partially) when I insert it in Slot 2.

When I insert it in Slot 1, it says "No SIM card detected".

Note:

1. If I use any other SIM, it works on either slots.
2. When I this SIM on other android phones or even a feature phone, it works correctly without any issue whatsoever.
3. I've already tried the "Reset Network Settings" feature. Ideally I don't want to reset my phone completely

Comment: Check the surface of the affected SIM card. Is it filthy or are there any serious scratches on the connection plates?

Comment: @Robert Nope. I bought this SIM just 3 months ago.

Comment: Had the exact same issue, ended up getting a new SIM card a few months ago. Now same thing happened again after I disabled the SIM for another reason... any ideas how to fix without getting a new SIM each time?